# N1QL Edit object inside array

Tags: database, couchbase, sql++

I have documents inside a Couchbase bucket that contain an array of objects.
I'm trying to simultaniously edit two distinct objects contained in an array of the same document.

I'm currently running the following query to edit one of these objects :

```
UPDATE mydoc SET x.myfield = $1 FOR x IN mydoc.myarray WHEN x.`key` = $2 END;
```

Is there a way I can run several queries like this concurrently as I'm editing two distinct subdocuments ?

I had a look at the subdoc API which doesn't seem to offer this capacity, but if there's a way, I'm keen to use it instead of a raw N1QL query.

Is my only option to lock the whole document then unlock it when I'm done with my update ?
I'm using the GoCB client if that's of any help.

Thank you !

Comment: (Couchbase SDK dev here)  The SubDocument API doesn't support predicates like this.  To do this with KV you'll want to get the full document, make any changes, and send it back.  No need to lock the document though, as you can use CAS optimistic concurrency instead.

Comment: Thanks for you answer ! I was initially doing an N1QL query instead of getting/setting the full document because I assumed (and I might be wrong) It'd be more performant than doing one N1QL query to retrieve the id of the document (as I don't have it at first) and then getting the whole document by this id, looping over the array to find the right entry, updating it and then saving everything back. Any hints on that ? I have no idea how KV/N1QL updates compare in terms of performance. Also, if I decide to keep the N1QL query, is there an optimistic way of handling concurency such as with KV ?

Answer (score 0):

WHERE clause controls what document to UPDATE and SET clause controls what to update. You need WHERE clause to avoid unnecessary mutations.

```
UPDATE mydoc SET x.myfield = $1 FOR x IN mydoc.myarray WHEN x.`key` = $2 END
WHERE ANY v IN mydoc.myarray SATISFIRS v.`key` = $2 AND v.myfield != $1 END;
```

Above statement updates all matched fields in the array.
Why do you need update multiple statements concurrently. There is no restrictions. But note to update to document needs to be fetched, modified and and written back. In between some other thread modifies CAS will mismatch and error will return and you need to handle that case.

Comment: The query I originally stated above seems to be working just fine, what I'm asking is how can I run several of them (or an other way to do the update, as I said I'm fine using the SDK) concurrently. I don't have a need for multiple queries, but it's a case that can sometimes happen in my code on different threads and that I need to be able to deal with.

Comment: Also, do you mean that my query without the WHERE will update every single document even if they don't match ?

Comment: Yes. It may update same document as it is. That is the way SQL standard UPDATE works. Once you use WHERE clause no update needed it will no-op. You need to handle multiple updates your self. In N1QL there is no locks. only control is through CAS value.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that and thought the 'WHEN' was enough to do this filtering bit. Not sure however how I should use the CAS while updating with N1QL. The doc is pretty straightforward about how to use it with the KV sdk but not so much about how it works when using n1ql.